# how to open popup like Ola fare card in Android

Tags: android, popup, android-alertdialog

I am working on cab booking app.I need to open popup like ola as click on car, popup will display and if we click on another car in same popup values get update.

I am able to open popup but that popup will overlay on entire screen. i need to open popup and at the same time below popup screen also must be clickable.Like in ola dialog display and we can click below car category as well.

Please any one help me out.Thank you.

Comment: try adding the view example and show some research effect (what have u done up to now)

Answer (score 0):

By default when a `Dialog` is in foreground, nothing is 'clickable' on the activity behind it.
And when you click on the window outside of the `Dialog`, by default it dismisses the current `Dialog`.

On a `Dialog` like `AlertDialog` you can set this flag: [FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL)

For example:

```
mDialog.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL,
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL);
```

Also check this answer (achieves the same thing): https://stackoverflow.com/a/33853487/2686502