# How to specify android window size

Tags: java, android

Per [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13654861/how-can-i-get-the-size-of-the-android-application-window-and-not-the-physical-sc#) you can fairly easily get the size of your application window. What I was wondering is, is it possible to manually set the size of an application window? Think something like [Samsung's floating window](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/10-lesser-known-galaxy-s7-features-need-know/), sort of. Clearly it can be done as Samsung is capable of doing it and there are ROMS that can do it as well, but I presume those are features that are baked into the framework. Is there a way to do this without root (or even with root if I can still do it via java and not having to manipulate the actual OS).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try one of these answers

1- set absolute numbers in Window.setLayout() to change the activity size .
and use relative layout to overlay the activity >> for more explanation refer to the second answer for this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7878235/overlay-an-activity-on-another-activity-or-overlay-a-view-over-another)

2- refer to this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33853311/how-to-create-a-floating-touchable-activity-that-still-allows-to-touch-native-co) to create floating activity

Comment: I presume this is the Window Manager received via Context.getSystemService?

Comment: To add to this, yes this does work. However it does not give the desired effect. The window when resized, will simply show a black background. Is it possible to have it show the actual homescreen behind it? Not the wallpaper, but the legitimate homescreen?

Comment: I've edited the answer .. the second choice is far better for what you want .

Comment: I was thinking too narrow minded. I am aware of how to make a floating activity, but still I think this is the correct answer for what I am trying to accomplish. Thanks!